# Search for values in a XML and overwrite them

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to find the value of a feature in a XML file and overwrite it with another value if it matches the "if" clause.

There are hundreds of tags called "feature" and every one has the same parameters with different values. I am having trouble with the navigating through the tags because I cannot distinguisch among the "feature" tags.

This is the configurarion file of a printer driver and it has about 10000 lines.
This is a small part of the XML. I need to check if the value of

```xml
<current_option>AUTO</current_option>
```

is different from "PLAIN", if so I have to overwrite it with "PLAIN". In this case I should overwrite "AUTO" with "PLAIN".

The Tag i need to find and change is in this structure:

$xml.device.software.component.factory.printing.feature[0].option[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMaoU.png).feature[5].current_option

You can find it on this screenshot at Line 1022:

[Structure of the XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMaoU.png)

```xml
<feature resource_id="550" caption_id="10017" typical="TRUE">
  Media_Type
  <current_option>AUTO</current_option>
  <option resource_id="558"> AUTO </option>
  <option resource_id="559"> PLAIN </option>
  <option resource_id="40551">HP_MATTE_90G</option>
  <option resource_id="30595"> LIGHT </option>
  <option resource_id="566"> BOND </option>
  <option resource_id="567"> RECYCLED </option>
  <option resource_id="30646">HP_LJC_MATTE_105G</option>
  <option resource_id="40552">HP_LJPREM_CHOICE_120G</option>
  <option resource_id="30649">HP_PRES_SOFT_GLOSS_120G</option>
  <option resource_id="10140">HP_PRES_GLOSS_130G</option>
  <option resource_id="30598"> MIDWEIGHT_96_110G </option>
  <option resource_id="30622"> HEAVY </option>
  <option resource_id="30599"> GLOSS </option>
  <option resource_id="30633"> HEAVY_GLOSSY </option>
  <option resource_id="10141">HP_CLJ_BROCHURE_MATTE_160G</option>
  <option resource_id="10142">HP_CL_BROC_GLOSSY_160G</option>
  <option resource_id="30624"> EXTRA_HEAVY </option>
  <option resource_id="30625"> EXTRA_HEAVY_GLOSSY </option>
  <option resource_id="40555">HP_COVER_MATTE_200G</option>
  <option resource_id="10143">HP_CL_PHOTO_GlOSSY_220G</option>
  <option resource_id="30626"> CARDSTOCK176 </option>
  <option resource_id="30615"> CARDGLOSSY </option>
  <option resource_id="562">TRANSPARENCY</option>
  <option resource_id="574"> LABELS </option>
  <option resource_id="561"> LETTERHEAD </option>
  <option resource_id="551"> ENVELOPE </option>
  <option resource_id="560"> PREPRINTED </option>
  <option resource_id="564"> PREPUNCHED </option>
  <option resource_id="30617"> COLOR </option>
</feature>
</option>
<option resource_id="5281">
SeparatorPageAlt
<constraint> CheckHPJobSeparatorPageInstalled </constraint>
<feature resource_id="5277" caption_id="10162">
  UserName
  <current_option>FALSE</current_option>
  <option resource_id="10"> TRUE </option>
  <option resource_id="9"> FALSE </option>
</feature>
<feature resource_id="5278" caption_id="10163">
  FileName
  <current_option>FALSE</current_option>
  <option resource_id="10"> TRUE </option>
  <option resource_id="9"> FALSE </option>
</feature>
```

I am not able to get to the value of "AUTO" to check if it matches the "if" clause

This is what I tried:

```bsh
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $Config.FullName)
$xml2 = $xml.device.software.component.factory.printing.feature |
        where {$_.resource_id -eq "550"}
```

or

```bsh
$xml2 = $xml | Where-Object {$_.current_option -eq "AUTO"}
```

or

```bsh
$xml2 = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath "//feature[@resource_id='550']/current_oprion"
```

Comment: What do you want to happen with `<current_option>FALSE</current_option>`?

Comment: I'm afraid this is very difficult to answer, because the xml part you are showing is not valid. Please provide a well formed xml where the whole structure is visible, of course shortened so that unnecessary repeating tags are removed. Now, it is unclear in which tags the `<feature>` tags are nested.

Comment: It should't be changed

Comment: @theo it is nested like this: device.software.component.factory.printing.feature.current_oprion

Answer (score 1):

This will find all tags `current_option` with value not equal to `PLAIN`

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $Config.FullName
$notplain=$xml | Select-Xml -XPath "//current_option[.!='PLAIN']"
```

Please note that tags and values are case-sensitive in XPath.

Comment: Ok but i jaust have to find this specific tag wich is inside this specific feature. There are a lot af feature tags and I need to find and eventually overwrite ONLY this one ```<feature resource_id="550" caption_id="10017" typical="TRUE">
  Media_Type
  <current_option>AUTO</current_option>```

Comment: Then please specify in your question exact condition you're need, not in comments.

Comment: This ist already described in my question: I need to check if the value of

<current_option>AUTO</current_option>

is different from "PLAIN", if so I have to overwrite it with "PLAIN". In this case I should overwrite "AUTO" with "PLAIN".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this inside a loop that references the $file:

`(Get-Content $file.FullName) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '<current_option>AUTO</current_option>', "<current_option>PLAIN</current_option>"} | Set-Content $file.FullName -Encoding unicode`

I am assuming unicode encoding here, if not you can remove that `-Encoding unicode` part.

Comment: I cannot use this because there are other tags that are called the same and don't need to be changed. This is my problem, i have to overwrite only this one.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: It's unclear whether you want to match `AUTO` values only, or any value that is *not* `PLAIN`; if the latter, use `current_option[.!='PLAIN']` and `$_.current_option -ne 'PLAIN'` below.</sup>

The simplest and most efficient way is to use the methods of `[xml]` (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`) directly, using an extended version of your XPath query to also check the value of the `current_option` element:

```
$n = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//feature[@resource_id='550']/current_option[.='AUTO']")
if ($n) { $n.InnerText = 'PLAIN' }
```

---

The following solutions build on your own solution attempts, but they will be slower:

You simply need to extend your `where` (`Where-Object`) filter script block to also check the `current_option` element's value and, if it matches, update that element using a `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) call:

```
$xml.device.software.component.factory.printing.feature |
  Where-Object { $_.resource_id -eq '550' -and $_.current_option -eq 'AUTO' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.current_option = 'PLAIN' }
```

Alternatively, with your XPath-based approach via `Select-Xml` (this is the the virtual equivalent of the solution at the top, but slower):

```
$xml |
  Select-Xml -XPath "//feature[@resource_id='550']/current_option[.='AUTO']" |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Node.InnerText = 'PLAIN' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the worst answer if the XML object or file is valid. But this works if the provided XML structure stays invalid:

```
$y = Get-Content z.xml
$resourceLines = ($y | select-string -pattern '<feature resource_id="550"' -SimpleMatch -AllMatches).LineNumber
$optionLines = ($y | select-string -pattern '<current_option>AUTO</current_option>' -SimpleMatch -AllMatches).LineNumber
$featureEndLines = ($y | select-string -pattern '</feature>' -SimpleMatch -AllMatches).LineNumber

foreach ($resourceLine in $resourceLines) {
    $begin = $resourceLine
    $end = $featureEndLines.where({$_ -gt $resourceLine},'First')[0]
    $optionLines.where({$_ -gt $begin -and $_ -lt $end}) |% { $y[($_-1)] = $y[($_-1)] -replace "AUTO","PLAIN" }
}

$y | Set-Content z.xml
```

Comment: Hi, the XML comes from a official printer driver of HP. This is the Structure: $xml.device.software.component.factory.printing.feature[0].option[1].feature[5].current_option

Comment: I edited my question and added a picture of the xml :)